# Magento how to change the default order status in Paypal

Tags: php, magento, paypal, status

i am new in Magento world. i have 1.4.2  currently when a customer place an order using Paypal the order status will be processing. I need to be pending.

i tried to change the default order status in config.xml in app/Core/code/Mage/Paypal/etc

```
<sales>
        <order>
            <statuses>
                <!-- retained for backwards compatibility, not used anymore -->
                <pending translate="label"><label>Pending</label></pending>
            </statuses>
        </order>
    </sales>
```

EDIT: http://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking/issue?issue=7572 this include a bug about wrong order status and the solution for Magento 1.3.2.4. but it is not applicable for 1.4.2
but that did not work. 
Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find a solution. 
in app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Controller/Express/Abstract.php

below link will show u how to change the state of an order whenever you want.

http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-how-to-change-order-status-programmatically/

so before you get redirected to the success page. change the order state to what ever you need.